# Preview displaying images in inches

Tags: macos, catalina, preview

Can Preview display images using inches in macOS Catalina? Is there a way to change it?

Comment: As opposed to what? The OS doesn't actually know how big an inch is on your screen. [The info could be worked out, knowing image DPI and display dimensions, resolution & dot-pitch… but no OS actually does this.]

Comment: The Inspector shows that the image is 756 × 756 pixels at 72 pixels/inch. So if I divide 756 by 72, I'll get the dimensions in inches?

Comment: You can get the dimensions in inches **when printed at 72DPI**. Until an image is printed, it doesn't have a DPI, it only has dimensions in pixels. The image size as viewed on your screen depends on all the values I mentioned above.

Comment: I asked the same question on ehMac. They were quite helpful.

Comment: I hope they gave you the right answers - because it's amazing how few people actually understand how this works. You could add your own answer below.

Comment: Hi Tetsujin, between you and them I got the info I needed. Thanks a bunch.